# Organic groups: permissions groupadmin not respected

Tags: organic-groups

I am having troubles getting organic groups permissions working.

In my grouptype I want to give the groupadmin the permission to edit the group.

> **On an OG level:**
>
> *admin/config/group/permissions/node/mygrouptype*

I have set the permissions to 'Edit group' for administratormember

> **On a Global level:**
>
> *admin/people/permissions*

I have set the permission to Edit 'Mygrouptype'

However still my groupadmins are not able to edit their group. Setting this permission on a groupmember level does give the groupadmin the permission.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps solved my problem:

1.On admin/config/group/settings i selected a default administrator member

2.and disabled the : 'Strict node access permissions' setting.

3. On admin/config/group/permissions/node/mycontenttype i disabled the administer group permission.